# Is there a way to make conform work during development?

Tags: elixir, conform

I have Conform configuration working in a Phoenix app.  This requires an exrm release.  For development purposes we want to use the same configuration technique, but without generating a release every time we make changes. Is there a way to use Conform when running `mix phoenix.server`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the intent is that you use Elixir's configuration functionality for test and development and that Conform is only used for releases.

Comment: We never figured out a way to do it, so I'll accept this answer.